Moving Ceph OSD daemons to a new service specification
I had a service specification that assigned all free SSDs to OSDs:
service\_type: osd  
service\_id: 34852880  
service\_name: 34852880  
placement:  
  host\_pattern: '*'  
spec:  
  data\_devices:  
rotational: false  
  filter\_logic: AND  
  objectstore: bluestore

I want more control over which drives each server assigns so I created a new specification as follows:
service_type: osd  
service_id: 34852881  
service_name: 34852881  
placement:  
  host_pattern: 'host1'  
spec:  
  data_devices:  
rotational: false  
  filter_logic: AND  
  objectstore: bluestore

In Ceph Dashboard -> Services I could see that my old OSD daemons continued to run under the control of the old service definitions. I deleted the old service definition. I got a warining:
If osd.34852880 is removed the the following OSDs will remain, --force to proceed anyway ...

As I thought keeping the daemons going is what I want I continued with --force. Now Ceph Dashboard -> Services lists the OSDs and "Unmanaged" and the new service definition still has not picked them up. How can I move these OSD daemons under the new service specification?
If I stop the daemons new ones do not get started by the new service definition. If I redeploy the daemons they still show as "unmanaged". The only way I can get them to move under the new service definition is to stop the daemon and zap the drive. However this is not a practical solution given the size of the cluster.
Given that the data is present and correct I am surprised there is no way to bring stray daemons to heal. (I have looked at the docs about stray daemons but they only reference the context of upgrading the cluster to cephadm).

This is not a programming question, you should ask it on serverfault or stackexchange. And if you do, please provide the full output of ‚ceph orch ls osd --export‘. One workaround is to edit the unit.meta file and specify the desired service name there.

@eblock You are quite correct. I have reposted it here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1166205/moving-ceph-osd-daemons-to-a-new-service-specification
